# SQL date reconstruct

Tags: sql

Guys i have following sql query , that does some mathematical calculation and outputs like this 1.40672427843473E18  , i need to reverse engineering to get the date back.

```
SELECT (TO_DATE('01112010','DD-MON-YY'))*POWER(2,44)+POWER(2,60) FROM DUAL
```

to get the original date back i did this

`SELECT (1.40672427843473E18/POWER(2,44))-POWER(2,60) FROM DUAL`

```
 // is this right way to reconstruct
 // original date.
```

but i get a negative value.kindly advise on this.

Comment: What does your mathematical calculation output? Seconds? Milliseconds from some epoch?

Comment: 1.40672427843473E18 is the output

Comment: I understand that `1.40672427843473E18` is the putput. But what is this `1.40672427843473E18` ? Seconds or milliseconds or some other number? Only based on this we can 'reconstruct' the date.

Comment: Ah, I understand. See kel's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented incorrect reverse function. It should be:

```
(1.40672427843473E18 - POWER(2,60)) / POWER(2,44)
```